# How to cancel a bunch of tasks when any of these tasks throws an exception?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I create and start many tasks. 
One of the task can throw an exception. If this happens I need to stop all the tasks.

Now I just see the only way to do this is to pass CancellationTokenSource to each task and call Cancel() in catch block.

Does TPL support the required feature in a more generic way?

Something like:

```
Action<Task> onExceptionAction = t => cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
var task = Task.WhenAnyThrows<MyException>(tasks, onExceptionAction);
```

And task is considered to be completed (or cancelled) if no exception is thrown

Comment: Seems to me that the cancellation support is pretty generic. You just need one `CancellationTokenSource` that you can pass to all of the tasks. You only have to call `Cancel` once on that token to cancel all of the tasks that use it. Seems pretty generic to me.

Comment: Well, it's ok, but what if you have some task producer? You recieve from it the cancellable tasks with associated CancellationTokenSource. And you have no control of the exception handling inside this task in this case. You can cancel this task with linked CTS created with the call to CreateLinkedTokenSource method. Nevertheless you can not embed the cancellation action inside the task. Yes, this example a bit artificail yet plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174.aspx) with [`TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx).

So, your method could look like:

```
void CancelWhenAnyFaults(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks)
        task.ContinueWith(
            _ => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Current);
}
```

I am passing the `CancellationToken` to `ContinueWith()` too, so that when one task fails, the other continuations are not executed.

Comment: Why OnlyOnFaulted I would think NotOnFaulted or NotOnCancelled ?

Comment: @Blam You want to do something (cancel the token) when the `Task` faults, that's why `OnlyOnFaulted`.